# How to make a controller for a universal washing machine motor?

Tags: motor-controller, induction-motor

I found a broken 2000ish Whirlpool washing machine called AWT4085 in a junkyard. I bought it for a school project like 'E Waste can be reused' topic. It was like  10 bucks or so. It had a lot of errors in electrical system. I removed everything, tested and cleaned them, and fixed things that works.

I fitted a normal voltage regulator to it. It worked but the issue was it dropped running speed when I added water. Unfortunately it broke.

I gave it up for like 7 months, then I found a controller called the [TDA1085C](https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/W59385ASP5_Speed_Control_TDA1085_Update.html).

As you can see there are a lots of comments from me.

After I made it, it started to blow the TRIAC and the IC (and R16, R13 also. I used both BTA12 and BT138.) It blew 5 of them with no reason.

What happens is that the TRIAC shorts between gate, base terminal 1 and 2. Really 2 TRIACs made that magic smoke. The motor seems to work fine (and the tacho.)

As I said, the TDA1085C is blown (and R16 power resistor, R13 TRIAC gate driving resistor - details are in the website which I linked earlier.) The creator of this PCB said that a better one is there and he gave up on this. From that I screwed up.

Can someone help me to fix this or any suggestions to another controller IC? I want a DIY-friendly simple system.

Details:

Website of this [PCB](https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/W59385ASP5_Speed_Control_TDA1085_Update.html).

Picture of the built circuit:

[image: Built circuit]

Schematic:

[image: Schematic]

PCB that he claims is better than this:

[image: Better schematic]

Website of this [PCB](https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Universal_motor_speed_controller_with_acceleration_control.html)

Motor label (it's a brushed motor):

[image: Motor label]

Update:

Now no resistors or ICs blow, but the TRIAC still blows when P2 (in the schematic) is adjusted.

Comment: Can you post schematics?

Comment: Post the picture of motor label. Old washing machine used asynchronous motor with start winding.

Comment: @JayasankaBandara the question needs more documentation before we can reopen it, can you post schematics? (if you edit the question you can use the tool to draw one)

Comment: @VoltageSpike
I added info what you all requested! So I wish I can get your help. And I don't know they said my question is closed!